# Add SD card to Fusion Drive in MacBook Pro 12,1

Tags: fusion-drive

I want to know if it's possible to add a 128 GB SD card to my MacBook Pro 12,1 (13-inch Retina, early 2015) and make 250 GB Fusion drive.

```
$ sudo diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +120.5 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 D3021BC9-8BCA-40BA-9B7C-07F28BDE678B
                                 Unencrypted
/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *129.8 GB   disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS Transcend               129.8 GB   disk2s1
```

```
$ sudo diskutil cs list

CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)

Logical Volume Group 878F63CA-69DB-43F2-8708-271D776049F5

=========================================================

    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         120473067520 B (120.5 GB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 0303DA39-F711-42D5-AB0B-7C35015763B3
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120473067520 B (120.5 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family EA26D69A-ED32-4088-BBF5-DD4ED4A01FE2
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        Reversion State:         Reverting
        High Level Queries:      Not Fully Secure
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume D3021BC9-8BCA-40BA-9B7C-07F28BDE678B
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          120473067520 B (120.5 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   Complete
            Revertible:            No
            Revert Status:         PV to LV passthrough mode
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Following an iBook from Carlos Burgues & Pablo Romeu called "Fusion Drive, Crea tu propia unidad Fusion drive en tu Mac" I think the commands would be:

```
sudo diskutil cs addDisk 878F63CA-69DB-43F2-8708-271D776049F5 disk2s1
diskutil cs resizevolume D3021BC9-8BCA-40BA-9B7C-07F28BDE678B 249,8g
```

But I'm not sure how to make it work properly and I have some questions about the process:

- Can I make changes directly on disk, or I must boot from another source to add the 128 GB SD card?
- Is it better to restore a carbon copy (or Time Machine) to a new & formatted 250gb Fusion drive?
- Will I loose the Recovery HD?
- Is there a better way to do this? (something like tardisk Pear software)

I really appreciate you to try to help me, but please, really, don't answer with something like: Don't do it (SD cards are no reliable, bad speeds, etc), or buy a better laptop, or something similar. The HDD can't be upgraded, so I want to try this solution.

Comment: Give up now. Really. SD cards are nowhere *near* reliable enough to do this, even if you can find a way to force it.

Comment: Please don't try to reformat Terminal output. I've attempted to format it correctly but feel free to edit further.

Comment: After your edit - I get through literally thousands of SD cards for work. I wouldn't trust one to hold **any** data that was not simply a copy of a master held elsewhere. The fail-rate on SDs is alarming. If you have one in effect 'RAIDed' to your internal drive, then at the first hint of a fail, you've lost the entire thing, not just the SD half.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a RAID 0 Striped Array. Here is how to do it: https://www.lifewire.com/use-disk-utility-to-create-a-raid-0-striped-array-2260918

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score 0):

I have a 128GB SSD SD card installed on my MacBook Pro 12,1. The only reason it can't be done is because the 2 drives do not boot up at the same time and you cannot boot to the SD card. I don't know why apple did this, but if they didn't I could show you how to do it in disk utilities and not through terminal.